# Book where a boy with tattoos is destined to defeat an evil demon

Tags: story-identification, mythology

The book cover has a man with a yin yang tattoo on his shoulder and a dragon tattoo on his arm. His back is facing the front and in the background I believe there is a mountain or valley.

The story is about a boy with these tattoos who is destined to defeat an evil demon who was sealed away in a mountain. He comes into contact with a monkey whose duty is to train the boy to fight the demon.

While this is going on, his mother meets a monk while traveling on the road, and they end up falling in love. However at the end of the book she is kidnapped I believe by a demon of something like that and the monk has to go rescue her.

Please help me to identify the book, this is all I remember about the story but I was hoping that by now the sequel would have come out by now. But I can't remember the title! I read the book about three years ago, but I know it came out years before I read it. I believe it came out in the early 2000's and is a Chinese myth/folk tale type book

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Could you add any more details, such as when you may have read this?  It all helps!  Thanks and good luck :D

Comment: Thanks for explaining that the demon is evil.  At first I was thinking that it was one of those good demons.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [The Outlaws of Moonshadow Marsh - The Sign of Qin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786819189).

The cover does depict a tattooed boy with a dragon on his left arm, facing away towards a mountain surrounded by clouds. The boy is born with the sign of an outlaw, and is destined for death by his Emperor father. However, he is foiled by a monk and a trickster monkey. Additionally, just before his birth, a volcanic eruption looses a bunch of trapped demons.

He doesn't have a yin/yang symbol, but he does have a white circle with what looks like a small black sword, that could be mis-remembered as a yin/yang.

It was published in 2006, but unfortunately it doesn't look like book #2 or #3 was ever published.

Answer (score -1):

I remember this book, I vaguely remember it being called something like "The Monk With 1,000 Tattoos" or something like that. 6 years later lol

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you clarify your answer and find the exact name of the book, instead of just a guess?  Right now this may be a hint, but it's not exactly an answer.  (There don't appear to be any books matching "monk with * tattoos.")